# why does my css file when refreshed changes to index.html page in bracket editor

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie in Front end languages. I am having a difficulty with my CSS web display, whenever I get to write my CSS codes on Bracket editor,then get to link it with any of the html codes. For example using <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mine.css>..then get to refresh the CSS.mine page, it automatically displays my index.html codes page, which is not related to what I expect, in terms of it loading to other html pages I linked it with or I'm working with.

Please any solution, on how to overcome this challenge?

Thanks

Comment: can not understand what you want to do ? please edit question and give some exact details.

Comment: please explain your question. add sample code and screenshot  if needed. i would suggest to read stackoverflow documentation on how to ask a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am getting it right, but normally the web browsers render the html files in the project folder, when it comes to css files, they are used for styling the html page, so you have to link the css file to the html file you want to render, for example index.html and index.css. Then in the head of the index.html you put the link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

as an example. Then you save and reload(or if using any automated terminal just save). CSS files are only displayed in the linked html files, so this means